# Using AirPods on MacBook Pro causes the on-board speakers to produce static

Tags: macbook-pro, airpods

I have an early-2015 MacBook Pro (running the latest OS). I recently bought AirPods 2 and began using them primarily on my MacBook Pro. After I have used them with the MacBook Pro for a while (I don't know how long because I haven't measured), if I disconnect and use the on-board speakers, they produce sound with a lot of static -- enough to convince anyone the speakers have gone bad. I have to restart the laptop to get them to go back to normal. While they throw out the static, if I go back to using AirPods, the sound is fine.

Would anyone know what's happening and how I can prevent it?

Thank you.

Comment: idk of a true 'fix' but try launching Audio MIDI Setup in Applications/Utilities. Select your speaker output in the Audio Devices window & change the Format. Check what your AirPods use as defaults & see if internal speakers is similar. If they're not the same, try setting speakers to the same, otherwise toggle speakers 44 to 48 [or vice versa] then back again, see if it just 'jogs its elbow'. Also, if you run any 3rd party audio 'booster' etc, uninstall it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you. The Audio MIDI tool is a helpful suggestion. I noticed that the channel and frequency used by default for internal speakers is different from those for AirPods. However, no matter what value I change the format to for internal speakers after the sound goes berserk, it doesn't make a difference. Rebooting the system does, though, which I dislike. I don't use any third party audio solutions.

Comment: Ah, OK - it was just an idea. I've never used anything bluetooth, so I don't even know where to look next, sorry.